# issue with laravel returning to a route after completing function in controller class

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get a Laravel controller to return to a route after a create function is complete.

I have the following code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Community::create($request->validated() + ['user_id' =>auth()->id()]);
    Return to route('communities.index');
}
```

It is returning the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected identifier "Route", expecting ";"
```

I know I am overlooking something simple, please help.

Comment: share code as txt

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: `return redirect()->route('Communities.Index')`

Comment: Change the question to add the codeblocks instead of links to images, sorry for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For redirection: `return redirect()->route('Communities.Index');`

For redirection to previous route: `return redirect()->back();`

For redirection with payload:

`return redirect()->route('Communities.Index')->with('success', 'Item added to cart successfully!');`

`return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'This is an error message.');`

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something simple. What I had meant to use was to_route() and had missed the underscore... (massive stupid moment!)

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect()->route('Communities.Index')
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation around this answer, it will be more useful for other users